# Finding index of the same elements in a list

Tags: python

Suppose I have to find each index of letter 'e' in the word "internet":

```
letter = 'e'
word = 'internet'
idx = word.index(letter)
```

But this code gives only the first index. How can I find the rest of them?

Comment: Of course 'word' here is a `string`, not a `list`.

Comment: Curiosity compels me to ask, why do you want the indexes?

Comment: Yes, my mistake. Of course a string... I'm coding hangman game.

Comment: While I'm flattered to have my answer accepted, I refer you to the opening sentence: for a Hangman game, where you are seeking all instances a single letter in a string, Mark's answer is the one you want.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[Mark's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7658932/finding-index-of-the-same-elements-in-a-list/7658955#7658955) is better for a single letter. I'm adding this in case your real substring is longer than a single character.

If you want to use [`str.index()`](http://www.python.org/doc//current/library/string.html#string.index), it can take an optional `start` position and will `raise` a [`ValueError`](http://www.python.org/doc//current/library/exceptions.html#exceptions.ValueError) if the desired substring is not found:

```
>>> letter = 'e'
>>> word = 'internet'
>>> last_index = -1
>>> while True:
...     try:
...         last_index = word.index(letter, last_index + 1)
...         print last_index
...     except ValueError:
...         break
... 
3
6
```

Comment: If you're going to use this, I suggest sticking it into a generator function yielding the indexes.

Comment: @yak: quite agree. I was just giving a basic example.

Answer (score 13):

Try using [enumerate](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#enumerate) in a [list comprehension](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0202/):

```
[index for (index, letter) in enumerate(word) if letter == 'e']
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
word = 'internet'
letter = 'e'
[i for i in xrange(len(word)) if word[i] == letter]
```